# Postfix: redirecting an email to local user (User unknown in virtual alias table)

Tags: postfix, email-server, email-bounces

My question is similar to others, but their answers were unhelpful.

What I want to do: Send email from xyz@domain.com and route incoming mail to xyz@domain.com to multiple external (e.g. x@gmail.com) addresses. As an intermediate step, I want to have mail to xyz@domain.com delivered to a local user, but this fails

When I set, in `main.cf`,

```
myhostname = domain.com
mydomain = domain.com
```

and leave `virtual` options and `mydestination` at their defaults, I can send and receive email on that machine at myunixusername@domain.com.

However, I want to forward mail, so I add

```
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost # so that $myhostname is not included
virtual_alias_domains = domain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

and in `/etc/postfix/virtual` I have only one entry:

```
xyz@domain.com myunixusername
```

This makes the server unable to receive mail at xyz@domain.com: the logs say `status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)`. I take care to do `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual; sudo service postfix reload` each time. What causes this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that with this choice of `mydestination`, your `/etc/postfix/virtual` has to be

```
xyz@domain.com myunixusername@localhost
```

Not sure if there's a more elegant solution.